# Does Malachi 3:8-11 concern christians today?

Tags: offering, tithes

Is tithing a cardinal christian requirement?
Are there instances of *tithe* paying in the early church in the book of Acts of Apostles or in the Epistles?
Are Christians who don't pay tithe in danger of God's curse and anger?

Comment: Possibly this should be on SE-Christianity.

Comment: @Ofinni Daniel Welcome to BHSX and thanks for your question. Have you taken the tour to see how this site works?

Comment: Sorry, but we don't allow questions that ask whether something applies today as that's not really hermeneutics.

Answer (score 1):

All the commands of the Old Testament should be viewed by Christians in the light of Paul's claim that we have "died to the law"; "But now we are discharged  from the law, dead to that which held us captive, so that we serve not under the old written code but in the new life of the Spirit" (Romans ch7 v6, RSV). This does not leave us without moral guidance. It simply means that our guidance comes direct from the Spirit, not from the words of Moses.

In Galatians, Paul warns us very strongly against putting ourselves back into "bondage" by taking up again the burdens of the laws of the old covenant. In his time, the issue was circumcision, the message being that "every man who receives circumcision is bound to keep the whole law" (Galatians ch5 v2), and thus gives up the mode of salvation which comes through Christ without the law.

The curse in Malachi is a subsidiary of the "curse of the law" (i.e. the curse proclaimed by the law) which Paul warns us against in Galatians ch3 v10. But "Christ redeemed us from the curse of the law" (v13), so it is no longer applicable to us.

Comment: So Christians are free to worship other gods, dishonor their parents, murder, commit adultery, covet, lie, steal, etc.?

Comment: @RevelationLad No, because the Holy Spirit is now telling them not to do those things. I refer you back to the last two lines of my first paragraph. That's what "in the new life of the Spirit" means. When the Holy Spirit tells me to tithe, I will tithe.

Comment: Ok. Apologies for the flippant response. Let me rephrase. Does the Christian need to initiate every discussion with the Holy Spirit or are there some actions which are "self evident?" Obviously there are things the Christian does not need to ask the Spirit. Is tithing one? And is the question one of do I or where do I? Tithing in the OT was set by both and amount and a "to whom." Without a Temple, a singular location, is the question if or where?

Comment: @RevelationLad Unfortunately lack of certainty is one of the side effects of not having a law. It is one of the symptoms of living by faith (i..e in trust). Especially since, as I'm convinced, God spends more time communicating with our unconscious minds than he spends on more open communication. This helps to account for surviving conscience, and the basic commandments are "self-evident" enough as the kind of thing the God we know would want.

Comment: @RevelationLad Tithing is less obvious because God doesn't need things (even in the O.T., the point was more that people should have willingness to give). He also wants us to support his servants, as Paul observes, but the detail would have to depend on circumstances.

Comment: @StephenDisraeli - this is a wonderful example of cafeteria theology - picking what you want and leaving the rest.  What of Paul's statement a few verse later where he says, "So then, the law is holy, and the commandment is holy, righteous, and good."?  There are numerous other such statements of Paul.  Indeed, Jesus even said that He had not com eto do away with the law (Matt 5:17-19).

Comment: @Dottard The word "law" has more than one meaning. See Romans ch 3 v27. When Paul says we are freed from the law, he is talking abut the NOMOS ERGON. When Paul says the law is holy and just and good,he is talking about the NOMOS POIOU. The law of Moses and God's law- two different things. There is not space here to discuss which one Jesus was talking about.

Comment: @StephenDisraeli - agreed, but your answer makes no such distinction.  There is also the problem that I have actually met a number of people who claim that that they act by the law of faith and love and are instructed by the Spirit to have extra wives.  Now, before you dismiss this as "silly" (it is) how is one to know if we are being motivated by the correct spirit and the correct love and faith?  The answer is always that such must accord with the moral law which is eternal; but that brings us back to where we started!

Comment: @Dottard Unfortunately that's the dilemma of faith. Faith is all about coping with uncertainty. Once we start looking for certainty, we start drifting towards new laws or legalistic teachings.. This is where we all need the gift of "discernment of spirits", which I understand as "telling the difference between what does and what does not come from the Holy Spirit".

Answer (score -1):

There are many who advocate that all the laws in the Torah are still binding upon Christians and those who say that none of them is binding.  Neither is supported by the Bible.  In deciding which, if any are applicable we must recall several facts:

1. **Jesus explicitly says that He did not come to abrogate the law**:

- Matt 5:17-19 - Do not think that I have come to abolish the Law or the Prophets. I have not come to abolish them, but to fulfill them. For I tell you truly, until heaven and earth pass away, not a single jot, not a stroke of a pen, will disappear from the Law until everything is accomplished. So then, whoever breaks one of the least of these commandments and teaches others to do likewise will be called least in the kingdom of heaven; but whoever practices and teaches them will be called great in the kingdom of heaven.

We also have numerous statements of Paul:

- the law is essential because “through the law we become conscious of sin” (Rom 3:21, 7:7, 13),
- “we uphold the law by faith” (Rom 3:31),
- “the law is holy, and the commandment is holy, righteous and good” (Rom 7:12),
- “the law is spiritual” (Rom 7:14),
- “the law is good” (1 Tim 1:8),
- keeping the law is to do right (James 2:8).
- “Do we, then, nullify the law by this faith? Certainly not! Instead, we uphold the law.” (Rom 3:31).
- “What then? Shall we sin because we are not under law, but under grace? Certainly not!” (Rom 6:15);
- “we are now slaves of righteousness” (Rom 6:16), or,
- “slaves to God” (Rom 6:22);
- “And this is love, that we walk according to His commandments. This is the very commandment you have heard from the beginning, that you must walk in love.” (2 John 6);

2. **It is impossible to keep the Levitical laws** (and tithing is one such), because there is neither Levitical priesthood nor temple to which such laws can be applied - all such Levitical laws were intimately tied to the temple ritual.

Thus, since tithing was associated with, and part of the Levitical covenant, which was fulfilled by Christ as our Great High Priest (See Hebrews), tithing cannot be enforced any more than animal sacrifices.

Despite the above, many people have elected to voluntarily tithe, including some veryt famous and wealthy people.  But that is entirely a personal choice.

**APPENDIX - Historic Divisions of the "Law"**

A number of famous theologians have, without much Biblical support, no9minated several divisions of the Biblical law, for example:

- Thomas Aquinas discussed the tripartite law, moral, ceremonial, and judicial, in his “Summa Theologica”, section entitled "Treatise on the Law" and more specifically in questions 99-105.
- Luther appears to believe in a bipartite Law, when in The Bondage of the Will, he referred to "the civil or moral law”. (Luther Bondage CXLVI)
- Calvin, in book 2 of Institutes of the Christian Religion (2.7, 2.8.31), presented a bipartite view when he discussed the law, its moral and ceremonial aspects.  However, later, in book 4 of the Institutes (4.20.14), when he discussed civil government, he presented a tripartite law when he stated: "the well-known division which distributes the whole law of God, as promulgated by Moses, into the moral, the ceremonial, and the judicial law.”
- The Westminster Confession (1646) set out a tripartite law
- The Baptist Confession of Faith (1689) almost copies the Westminster Confession in assuming a tripartite law (see Chapter 19).  (According to the 2000 Baptist Faith and Message, no such division exists.)

This is all very well, except that such divisions, while convenient, are not actually expressed in the torah itself.  The only divisions we have are those between the 10 commandments, the Levitical laws and the general civil laws which are approximately those of Moral, ceremonial and civil.

Comment: Contemporary application is *off-topic*. As the highest rep user on the site, please help others learn how to use the site by not answering off-topic questions, and VTC the question itself.

Comment: I'd originally downvoted the answer as it doesn't actually mention Malachi in a question about Malachi. In retrospect the answer itself doesn't really merit the downvote, but rather the fact that it doesn't involve any exegesis of Malachi is more of a telltale sign that the question is off-topic.